# expand some wildcards within given string and return list of strings

Tags: tcl, expansion

Is it possible to write a proc which will give a string and will be expand some wildcards and will return list of strings, something like this:

```
proc expand_string { string } {
 ...
}

set a [expand_string {[1-5]a}]

puts $a #a is: 1a 2a 3a 4a 5a
```

The interested wildcards are:

`[12..a..z]`:
Match any character listed in the brackets.

`[a-z]`:
Match all characters between `a` and `z`.

`?(abc)`:
Match zero or one instance of `abc`.

Comment: Is that the only wildcard you'll be having? If you also have `*` and `?` (if grep wildcards) or `.*` and `\w` (if regex metachars) then it'll be *quite* complicated.

Comment: [Jerry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1578604/jerry). I have updated the question.

Comment: Well, it will be pretty complex IMO.

Comment: Possible? Sure. Easy? No. You might start with the [Tcl solution to this task on Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Brace_expansion#Tcl), as what you're asking for could be rewritten in terms of a translation into a brace expansion sequence…